# html range elemnt - move on tap event

Tags: javascript, html, events, input, range

I have a html input type range element (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/range).

Everything works as expected on pc (you can drag it, if you click on a specific place "on the line" it goes there). My problem is that on mobile I can drag the cursor (works fine), but when I tap somewhere the cursor doesn't move there.

Any idea how to fix this (how to make ontap work with range)?

So far I created a touchstart and a touchmove event, I get the current cursor position on screen and move the cursor according to it. Then make a touchend event and call the relevant code (basically I simulate an instant drag).

But the whole point of using a range was so I don't have to do this (is ugly and complicated for something it should be simple)... so... I guess there may be a better solution.

Comment: It is working fine (Codepen demo) On Mobile Google Chrome Browser

Comment: Not in IOS (safari) - tested directly using the w3c example.